# Terraform code is not recognised environment variable (TF_VAR variable)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I want to use environment variable in Terraform but my TF code is not recognised TF_VAR. I set as environment variable `export TF_VAR_test="some value"` and tried to use in my TF code `tempval = var.test`.

Using terraform  **v1.0.2**

What I missed here? please advise me. thanks.

Comment: Did you declare the variable?

Answer (score 4):

Before using a variable, one must [declare the variable in a variable block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#declaring-an-input-variable).

For example...

```
variable "test" {
  type = string
}
```